# How to loop on an array of ids sent by ajax request using laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to export multiple word files according to the ids sent by ajax request.

So I'm using the following script :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#numero_projet').change(function() {
    var id_projet = $(this).find("option:selected").data("id");
    $('#generer').click(function() {
      alert("hello");
      var checkValues = $('input[name=casting_checked]:checked').map(function() {
          return $(this).data('id');
        })
        .get();
      var join_selected_values = checkValues.join(",");
      $.ajax({
        url: "generer/"+id_projet+"/"+checkValues,
        type: 'get',
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        data: {
          ids: join_selected_values
        },
        success: function (data) { }
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

And the following controller :

```php
public function generer()
{
    if (request()->ajax()) {
        $id_projet = request('id_projet');
        $id_casting = request('ids');
        $idsArray=explode(",",trim($id_casting,','));
        if (!empty($idsArray)) {
            $id_contrat = Projet_Casting::where('id_projet',$id_projet)->whereIn('id_casting',$i)->value('id_contrat');
            $id_modele_contrat = Contrat::where('id_contrat',$id_contrat)->value('id_modele_contrat');
            $model_file = Model_Contrat::where('id_modele_contrat',$id_modele_contrat)->value('fichier');
            $templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor('/storage/app/public/uploads/modeles_contrat/'.$model_file);
            $filename= $id_contrat;
    
            $templateProcessor->saveAs( $filename.'.docx');
    
            return response()->download( $filename.'.docx');
        }
    }
}
```

If the `$idsArray` contains 3 ids it should generate 3 word files.

But with this code it generates only one document and not multiple document.

If you have any idea please help.

Comment: I think there is no way to that except if you use zip or something. What you could try is call the ajax request multiple times.

Comment: how can I call the ajax request multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to download multiple files in one request. You need a way to zip all the files first and then return the response to download that zip file.

Comment: how can I verify if it is not empty ?

Comment: please explain more if you can ,

Comment: I didn't understand your question in the beginning. Therefore, I have updated my answer now.

Comment: please check my second question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68490867/loop-on-a-multiple-element-sent-by-ajax-requast-using-laravel

Comment: Can you please explain what $templateProcessor is doing? Is it saving the file in the specified storage path? If yes, then you can first save all the files in a location using a loop first. Then you may use php ZipArchive class to zip the saved files in a loop and return the download response like mentioned here: https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-create-zip-archive-with-files-and-download-it-in-laravel/

Comment: the problme is it generates only one document